# Modern Delphi to C strings for passing to C DLLs

Tags: c, delphi

I've got some old C DLLs that serve as intermediaries between my Delphi app and MATLAB compiled DLLs. These were originally developed with Delphi 7, and worked fine. Now, however, I've upgraded first to XE7 and now to 10.2.3, and I'm having problems. Basically, I have to pass a pointer to a record to the DLL; the structure includes fields that are pointers to old-fashioned C-style strings (i.e. an array of chars, where each char is a byte, and terminated by a 0 byte).

So consider this record:

```
MyRec = record
  id: Integer;
  name: PByte;
end;
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
function MakeCString(S: String): TBytes;
var
  I: Integer;
  len: Integer;
begin
  len := Length(S);
  SetLength(Result, len + 1);
  if len > 0 then
    begin
      for I := 0 to (len - 1) do
        begin
          Result[i] := Byte(S[I + 1]);
        end;
    end;
  Result[len] := 0;
end;
```

Then, my intent is to use this like this:

```
var r: MyRec;
r.id := 27;
r.name := MakeCString('Jimbo');
callMatlabWrapperDll(@r);
```

I know this is ugly and prone to memory loss - if it even works reliably at all! It seems to sort of work, but now on a different Windows 10 machine from where it worked (maybe), on my dev machine (also Windows 10), I get errors.

I've banged my head on this long enough. What I need is a way to create a C-style string, pass its address to a DLL, and clean up afterwards. (Note: This is all Win32, running on Win64).

Thanks.

Comment: Your code won't handle non ASCII text properly. But there's no issue with memory leaks that can be seen here. And I don't see why this should give erroslrs where delphi 7 did not. But you didn't tell us what the error is. Or show the C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MakeCString()` is implemented wrong.  It is not converting Unicode characters to ANSI, it is just truncating the characters as-is from 16-bit to 8-bit, which is not the same thing.

For that matter, you don't actually need `MakeCString()` at all.  You can use `TEncoding.GetBytes()` instead.

Also, you are assigning the result of your "conversion" directly to your record's `PByte` field.  You should first assign it to a local `TBytes` variable, and then get a pointer to its data.

Try this instead:

```pascal
type
  MyRec = record
    id: Integer;
    name: PByte;
  end;

procedure callMatlab;
var
  r: MyRec;
  name: TBytes;
begin
  name := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes('Jimbo'#0);
  r.id := 27;
  r.name := PByte(name);
  callMatlabWrapperDll(@r);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can (and should) use `PAnsiChar` instead, which is what C-style APIs generally use for 8-bit strings, eg:

```pascal
type
  MyRec = record
    id: Integer;
    name: PAnsiChar;
  end;

procedure callMatlab;
var
  r: MyRec;
  name: AnsiString;
begin
  name := AnsiString('Jimbo');
  r.id := 27;
  r.name := PAnsiChar(name);
  callMatlabWrapperDll(@r);
end;
```

This would be more inline with your Delphi 7 code, when `String` was still `AnsiString`.

Comment: Thanks again, Remy. Your second example seems just the ticket. I'm trying to fully understand memory management though. Assume `name: AnsiString` is a local variable of a function, and the your code is in the body of the function, then when the function returns, is name properly disposed of? Is that the same as a String variable? I think yes to both - just trying to make sure. In my real code, the record lives longer, and I think that may be the real cause of my problem. I think I will create a class that holds the record (for Matlab) and the AnsiStrings, and use its destructor to clean up.

Comment: @Bob yes, the AnsiString is disposed of automatically when it goes out of scope, just like any other compiler-managed type is. Same with TBytes, too. If the record outlives the AnsiString/TBytes, then yes, you can end up with a dangling pointer in the record's `name` field. .

Answer (score 2):

Two things are important to note:

1. Since Delphi 2009, `string` is Unicode (that is, two bytes per character).
2. [Delphi strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Long_String_Types) are essentially C-style strings with an additional header.

The first point means that you must convert the strings from Unicode to ANSI. The second point means that you don't need to write a function that creates a C-style string from a Delphi string -- the Delphi string already is C-style if you just disregard its header. Simply casting a Delphi string to `PChar` gives you a pointer to the C-style string, because the header is at a negative offset from the string pointer's value.

If `MyDelphiString` is your Delphi `string`, this can be converted to an old `AnsiString` by a simple cast: `AnsiString(MyDelphiString)`. This will create a new string on the heap, with the same content but now in legacy ANSI format (1 byte per char). Of course you will lose "special" characters like ⌬∮☃电脑.

Let us save this to a local variable so we know that its lifetime is (at least) as long as this variable is in scope (thanks Remy Lebeau):

```
var
  MyAnsiString: AnsiString;
begin
  MyAnsiString := AnsiString(MyDelphiString)
```

And to get a pointer to the C-style string which is a subset of this string object, just write `PAnsiChar(MyAnsiString)`. If you insist on using a `PByte` type in the record, you can be explicit about this reinterpretation as well:

```
r.Name = PByte(PAnsiChar(MyAnsiString))
```

But it would be nicer if the record member's type was `PAnsiChar` instead of `PByte`.

Comment: You are creating a temporary `AnsiString` and then casting it. You should save the result of that cast to a local variable first to make sure the data stays in scope for as long as you need it, eg: `var AStr: AnsiString; ... AStr := AnsiString(MyDelphiString); r.Name = PByte(PAnsiChar(AStr));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that feels much safer, thanks. Even if I suspect all current compilers will not remove it until the `end` of the routine, this is just a feeling I have and probably not a guaranteed and documented fact. With a local variable, we get an explicit promise that its lifetime will be as long as that variable is in scope. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I can change to PAnsiChar, no trouble, even though to me PByte seems clearer - too much C/C++ in my day job, I guess! :)

Comment: @Bob it depends on what Matlab is actually excepting. `(P)AnsiChar` is equivalent to C's `char(*)`. `(P)Byte` is equivalent to C's `unsigned char(*)`

Comment: Yes, of course, that makes perfect sense. Really, it is my embedded background that makes me prefer Bytes (i.e. unsigned) over signed - sometimes, that leads me astray, I'm afraid.